# Как задать редирект на определенном каталоге сайта?

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, get, редирект

Есть один каталог на сайте, на котором в единичном порядке нужно у второго уровня вложенности убрать все возможные get-параметры. Пример ссылки: `site.ru/catalog/row?start=12`.
`row` может всегда меняться, `catalog` всегда неизменен, но проблема в том, что уже в `site.ru/catalog/row/line` есть полезные get-параметры

Comment: существующий `.htaccess` покажите

Comment: надо полгаать у вас там уже есть какое то правило которое преобразует путь и передает параметры с помощью `[QSA]` флага. Вот надо перед этим правилом добавить что-то вроде `^catalog/(.*?)/?$` с флагом `[L]`